# Whats wrong with my code

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I want tableRow.html to be drawn under the table head but the ng-repeat is not drawing at all and the examples are above the table head.  If I drop the row with examples directly into the proper location in index.html it will draw just fine.  What am I doing wrong?
index.html

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Currency Exchange</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/stylesheet.css"/>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/angular.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body ng-app="myApp">
    <h1>A title to the table</h1>
    <div>
        <div class= "ExTableDiv">
            <table class= "ExTable">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th class="column">Currency Code</th>
                    <th class="column">Currency Name</th>
                    <th class="column">Exchange Rate vs USD</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody ng-controller="TestController"><!--**if you try TestController as TC it will throw an error, why?**-->
                <test-directive></test-directive>
            </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/app.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/directives/tableFiller.js"></script>
</html>
```

app.js

```
(function(){
var app = angular.module('myApp',['exchange-directives']);

app.controller('TestController', ['$http', function($http) {
var table = this;
table.rows = [];
$http.get('/item.json').success(function(data){
    table.rows = [{"name":"Captain","rate":"0.8910","inverce":"1.1223"}]; //I added this here so I know I am getting json data
});
}]);
})();
```

tableFiller.js

```
(function(){
var app = angular.module('exchange-directives', []);

app.directive('testDirective', function(){
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        templateUrl: 'js/directives/tableRow.html'
    };
});
})();
```

tableRow.html

```
<tr ng-repeat='row in TestController.table.rows'>
<td>{{row.name}}</td>
<td>{{row.rate}}</td>
<td>{{row.inverse}}</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Example 1</td>
    <td>Example 2</td>
    <td>Example 3</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: can you edit yur question to ask one thing at once - do you want to know why you code does not work, or an answer to other question?

Comment: lets go with why the table is not working first, the question is edited

Answer (score 0):

Replace `<tr ng-repeat='row in TestController.table.rows'>` with
`<tr ng-repeat='row in TestController.rows'>`

In your controller you're setting `table = this`, so `table.rows` actually is `this.rows` and thus available to the markup via `TestController.rows`

Comment: I did what you said but it didn't change anything

Answer (score 0):

I am choosing to answer this question:

> Also the tutorial I followed on codeschool wraps angular.module within a function but I see that most other examples don't. What is the difference? Why choose one over the other?

This is called an [immediately invoked function expression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immediately-invoked_function_expression) or (IIFE). It is a light-weight way to introduce modules into JavaScript. The goal of using something like this is to ensure lexical scoping of all variables declared at the top level of the module. Without something like this, it is easy to accidentally introduce global variables, which in general is a baaaaad thing.